# Unramification of Ideals in Pure Cubic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I need some explanation for this .Let $K=\mathbb  Q{\sqrt[3]{m}} $ be a pure cubic field with non square element $\alpha $ in $K$ such that ideal $(\alpha) $ is an ideal square in K. Let $ L=K(\sqrt{\alpha})$ be a quadratic extension of K then why only primes above  2 and $\infty $  will ramify. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: An ideal square in $\mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: I think this is true when $K$ is any number field.

Comment: @Slade What is wrong with an ideal square? Perhaps you want to change the terminology to: $(\alpha)$ is a square in the group of ideals of $K?$

Comment: @awllower $K$ only has two ideals.

Comment: @Slade Well, it is a convenient way to say *the group of ideals in the ring of integers of $K.$* In any case, you haven't explained what your doubt was.

Comment: @awllower I didn't have a doubt.  I understand the notation, I just think it's worth specifying whether these are fractional ideals of $K$, or actual ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$.  It doesn't change the problem much, but in my opinion it's a distinction worth clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha$ be such an element.
$(\alpha) = \mathfrak p^2$, and the hypothesis on $\alpha$ says that $\mathfrak p$ represents a nontrivial element of order $2$ in the ideal class group of $K$.
The extension $L/K$ may be ramified at the primes above $2,\infty$, and at the primes present in the factorisation of $\mathfrak p$.

Now, in the ideal class group, each ideal class is represented by infinitely many prime ideals.
So we can find an ideal $\mathfrak q$ coprime with $\mathfrak p$ such that $\mathfrak {pq} = (a)$ for some $a \in K$

Now, we have $ (\alpha)\mathfrak q^2 = (a^2)$, so setting $\beta = a^2/\alpha$, we have $\mathfrak q^2 = (\beta)$, $L = K(\sqrt{\alpha}) = K(\sqrt{\beta})$, but $K(\sqrt{\beta})$ can only be ramified above the primes at $2$ and $\infty$, and at $\mathfrak q$.

Since $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$ are coprime, $L$ can only be ramified at the primes above $2$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Notice that, when $K$ is a number field containing a unit $u$ which is not a square, then perhaps $\mathfrak p$ is principal: e.g. In $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{7}),$ the element $\alpha=-8-2\sqrt 7$ is not a square, but $-\alpha=(1+\sqrt 7)^2.$ In fact, consider $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{7}):$ the element $\alpha=-1-2\sqrt[3]7-\sqrt[3]{49}$ cannot be a square (expand out $(a+b\sqrt[3]7+c\sqrt[3]{49})^2$), while $-\alpha=(1+\sqrt[3]7)^2,$ so that your proof needs to be modified.

Comment: hmm if $(\alpha) = (\beta^2)$ then $\alpha/\beta^2$ is a unit $u$ and $K(\sqrt \alpha) = K(\sqrt u)$ which can only be ramified at $2,\infty$, and the primes dividing $u$ (and there isn't any) ? I kinda felt at the time those pesky units would come and bite me *somewhere* but I couldn't find anything wrong with my proof so I wrote it like that lol

Comment: Well, it seems that you just finished the proof. +1 :)